# I want to get the value of each <td><button></td>. here it's my code so far

Tags: jquery

// SHOW ALL ORDERS TAKEN

// I wanna get the value of each select

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.api.verdulero.com/index.php/api/Pedidos/mostrar_fila?    id_pedido='+id_pedi,
    type:'get',                         
    success: function(response){       

    $("#tableOrder").show();
```

// DISPLAY EACH RECORD IN A TABLE

```
    $.each(response, function (index,producto){  
    $("#displayOrder").html(''); 


    ap += "<tr>";
    ap += "<td>"+producto.cantidad+"</td>";
    ap += "<td>"+producto.unidad+"</td>";
    ap += "<td>"+producto.producto_nombre+"</td>";
    ap += "<td>"+producto.fecha_entrega+"</td>";
    ap += "<td></td>";
    ap += "<td><button type='button' id='borrar' class='btn btn-danger' value='"+producto.id+"'>Borrar</button></td>";
    ap += "</tr>";


    }); 

    $("#displayOrder").append(ap); // display the orde
```

r

// FUNCTION TO DELETE AN ORDER.

```
$("#displayOrder button").each(function(){
        var i = $(this).val();
        $("#displayOrder").on("click","button", function(){
            alert(i);
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

// end of success display order's

Comment: I want to deleted each order if the client click, but i can't get each button with it own value

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear with the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop over all the button just for event listener. You can register once, and all of them are counted. See below code :

```
// event delegation used
// target all the button inside #displayOrder
$("#displayOrder").on("click","button", function(){
   // this is how you captured button's value
   // which in your case is a product ID
   var btnValue = $(this).val();
   // and this to remove button's row(clicked button row)
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Norlihazmey, It was that exacly I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#displayOrder").click('button', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```